# ARSCNView prepare crash when SCNMaterialProperty is SpriteKit scene

Tags: scenekit, arkit

I'm experiencing an ARKit/SceneKit crash.

It happens if I do the following:-

- Create SCNPlane and set the SCNMaterialProperty to a SpriteKit
  scene
- Create SCNNode with SCNPlane
- Call prepare on ARSCNView and add SCNNode.

It crashes when I call prepare. However, it does not crash if I add the SCNNode without calling prepare or if the SCNMaterialProperty is not a SpriteKit scene.

See code below:-

```
var exhibitScene = SKScene(fileNamed: spriteName.lowercased())
exhibitScene?.view?.preferredFramesPerSecond = 60
exhibitScene?.view?.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
exhibitScene?.scaleMode = .aspectFit
exhibitScene?.isPaused = false

let exhibitSize = CGSize.init(width: (exhibitScene?.frame.size.width)! / PIXEL_TO_CENTIMETRE, height: (exhibitScene?.frame.size.height)! / PIXEL_TO_CENTIMETRE)

let exhibitPlane = SCNPlane(width: exhibitSize.width/100, height: exhibitSize.height/100)
exhibitPlane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = exhibitScene
exhibitPlane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4Translate(SCNMatrix4MakeScale(1, -1, 1), 0, 1, 0)

let exhibitNode = SCNNode(geometry: exhibitPlane)
exhibitNode.name = name
exhibitNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = false
exhibitNode.position = SCNVector3(x/100, (y + Float(exhibitSize.height * 0.5))/100, z/100)

self.sceneView.prepare([exhibitNode], completionHandler: { (Bool) in
     self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(exhibitNode)
})
```

Not sure how to fix this.

Do I have to set a parameter on the ARSCNView for it to prepare a SCNNode when the SCNMaterialProperty is set to use a SpriteKit scene?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your case, but I had a similar crash when the size of SKScene (and consequently SCNPlane) was more than some limit. The actual reason for the crash was that `SCNMaterialProperty.contents` may not be bigger than some limit (I believe it was about 4000px or something).